# How to uninstall java6

Tags: apt, java, 8.04, purge

I am trying

```
root@vz10931:/var/www/mailer# apt-get remove --purge sun-java6-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run apt-get -f install to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  sun-java6-jdk: Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.24-1build0.8.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
  sun-java6-jre: Depends: java-common (>= 0.24) but it is not installable
                 Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.24-1build0.8.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                          ia32-sun-java6-bin (>= 6.24-1build0.8.04.1) but it is not installable
  vim: Depends: vim-common (= 1:7.1-138+1ubuntu3.1) but 2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Below is my sources.list

```
deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Ubuntu version - Hardy Heron

Anyone know how to remove java ?

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get -f remove sun-java6-bin` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`sudo apt-get --purge remove sun-java6-\* vim-common`

that will also remove 'vi' editor. 
You can use 'nano', 'pico' instead or try installing vim later

Comment: Still nothing. It is like vicious circle now I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:sun-java6-jre: Depends: java-common (>= 0.24)`

Comment: I just found solution `sudo apt-get --purge remove sun-java6-\* vim`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work on Hardy. It does on 9.x+. Please try the following command. It will remove all packages from sun-java6:

```
sudo apt-get purge sun-java6-\*
```

Comment: The same situation as above `The following packages have unmet dependencies:vim: Depends: vim-common (= 1:7.1-138+1ubuntu3.1) but 2:7.3.154+hg~74503f6ee649-2ubuntu3 is to be installed`